# How to delete image and file in my database and folder

Tags: laravel, sql-delete, delete-file

when I want to delete data, the data in the `rekap` table is deleted but the `file_rekap` table and `image_rekap` table and those in the folder also don't want to be deleted

> Controller Rekap

```
    public function delete_rekap($id){
    $data = rekap::findOrfail($id);
    $images=image_rekap::where("rekap_id",$data->id)->get();
    foreach($images as $image){
    if (File::exists("images_rekap/".$image->image)) {
       File::delete("images_rekap/".$image->image);
    }
    }
    $files= file_rekap::where("rekap_id",$data->id)->get();
    foreach($files as $file){
    if (File::exists("rekap_file/".$file->file)) {
       File::delete("rekap_file/".$file->file);
    }
    }
    $data->delete();
    return redirect()->route('rekap')->with('success','Data berhasil dihapus');
}
```

this my button

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger delete m-1" data-id="{{ $row->id}}" data-customer="{{ $row->customer}}" >DELETE</a>
```

script

```
 $('.delete').click(function(){
      var rekapid = $(this).attr('data-id');
      var customer = $(this).attr('data-customer');
      swal({
        title: "Yakin",
        text: "Kamu akan menghapus data dengan nama "+customer+" ",
        icon: "warning",
        buttons: true,
        dangerMode: true,
      })
      .then((willDelete) => {
        if (willDelete) {
        window.location = "/delete_rekap/"+rekapid+" "
          swal("Data Berhasil Terhapus", {
            icon: "success",
          });
        } else {
          swal("Data tidak jadi dihapus");
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

what steps should i do to fix it

Comment: There are 2 calls to `File::delete` method. If you wouldn't like to delete file, just remove its.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to delete, try
[unlink php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)